# Screen fade to black after 10 minutes and never come back

Tags: xorg, xbmc, framebuffer, linaro

Im using Linaro Raring Server for Cubieboard A20 from here:

[www.cubieforums.com/index.php?topic=807.0](http://www.cubieforums.com/index.php?topic=807.0)

After about 10 minutes, the screen goes to black, even I'm using keyboard or mouse, so seems not be a screensaver to me, since not idle.
Nothing I can do brings the screen back again, only a reboot.
My system still alive (my TV shows signal is active).

I'm not using GUI, so answer in terminal commands.

I don't use GUI, but have a X11, because xbmc is installed on system. At startup, xbmc starts without login.

Steps I've done:

1) Start system and XBMC. Auto login (root). Black screen after 10 min even using keyboard/mouse.

2) Start without XBMC (and GUI). Auto login (root). Black screen after 10 min even using keyboard/mouse.

Tried this 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1072531

and this
[How to stop screen going black after 10 min](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291135/how-to-stop-screen-going-black-after-10-min)

I don't have xset and can't find where xorg.conf is.

There is a X11 in init folder.
XBMC is using framebuffer.

Comment: Does this happen with other (non-root) user? Linaro Raring Server is not even Ubuntu! Also, it says **"!! Unstable release !!"** in red letters in the post that you linked. It also apparently uses saucy witch is another reason why it is offtopic. You should ask in their forums.

Comment: Yes. This warning refers to use of xbmc in cubieboard (the CedarX drivers is in tests)

Comment: @Braiam I think the main question is how to disable the "screen saver" when there is no GUI, only framebuffer. I have no xset. Maybe kernel boot commands? Maybe tty0 settings? I appreciate anything you have in mind.

Comment: @MagnoC: It would be your display manager which is causing the problem. I want you to post the output of these commands: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` and `ls /etc/sbin/*dm`. Reply..

Comment: @Saurav Kumar I figured out by adding `consoleblank = 0` in /boot/uEnv.txt file. I think this file is the same as kernel commands in boot process. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MagnoC: Good to know that you solved your issue.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out by adding `consoleblank = 0` in `/boot/uEnv.txt` file. I think this file is the same as kernel commands in boot process.

```
extraargs = disp.screen0_output_mode=1280x720p60 consoleblank=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the option "LOCK_SCREEN" to false in /etc/default/acpi-support

Another place to try is via grub, edit /etc/default/grub, change
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
to
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: I don't have grub. I don't know the boot process in details, but I have a DOS partition with some files (uEnv.txt, boot.scr, etc ... by the way, the boot is in a SDCARD). I will try your other tip.

Comment: I think the boot is U-Boot (http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/WebHome)