# How to stop screen going black after 10 min Ubuntu Mate

Tags: xorg, lightdm, screen, mate

I have the same question as this:
[How to stop screen going black after 10 min](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291135/how-to-stop-screen-going-black-after-10-min)
 but with Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and an equivalent `mate-power-manager-seetings` does not exist. There is mate-power-statistics, mate-power-prefferences,mate-power-manager for options, but i have looked at these, and they are set in such a way that one would think the screen would never go blank, but still, every 10 minutes, the screen goes blank.

Ive looked at nummerous forum posts about how to stop screen blanking. 
some say edit /etc/kbd/config,
others say edit xorg, or lightdm.conf. 
all, seem to only work sometimes. I want the solution that will work every time.

I am running a kiosk, and I need the screen to stay lit, and displaying, what can I do?

Comment: Have you looked in the screen saver preferences (`mate-screensaver-preferences`) in case a Blank screen saver has been set?

Answer (score 3):

You should try to find `mate-power-manager`.

If it doesn't exist, you can install it by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo apt install mate-power-manager
```

After installation, you can access it either via

- Terminal: by typing `mate-power-preferences`
- GUI: System > Control Center > Power Management and/or Screensaver (for your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Install caffeine. It will solve your issue. To install, use this command

```
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

in a Terminal by summoning it with Ctrl-Alt-T

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/599917)

Comment: @DavidFoerster He suggested to install caffeine :)